# Cannot Assign value

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am stuck a bit. I want to check and validate my variables in TRec where any of them is empty or something. The main problem is after I validated the record it is not changed. I dont know what is the problem.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my example:

```
  TRec = record
    Name: string;
    Age: string;
    etc...
  end;  

  TParameterRec = record
  private
    fRec: TRec;
    procedure SetRec(Value: TRec);
  public
    property Rec: TRec read fRec write SetRec;
  end;

  TSampleClass = class
  private 
    fParameters: TParameterRec;
  protected
    ValidateParameters; 
    ValidateParameters_Record(aRec: TRec);    
  public
    property Parameters: TParameterRec read fParameters write   SetParameters;
  end;

  procedure TSampleClass.SetParameters(Value: TParameterRec);
  begin
    fParameters := Value;
    ValidateParameters;
  end;

  procedure TSampleClass.ValidateParameters;
  begin
    ValidateParameters_Record(fParameters.Rec);
  end; 

 procedure TSampleClass.ValidateParameters_Record(
   aRec: TRec);
 begin
   if aRec.Name = '' then
    aRec.Name := 'something';  //Here nothing happens, outside name will be empty 
 end;

procedure TParameterRec.SetRec(Value: TRec);
begin
  fRec := Value;
end;

....
var
  SampleClass: TSampleClass;
  ParamRec: TParameterRec;
begin
  SampleClass := TSampleClass.Create;
  try
    ParamRec.Rec := SomeRec; //It has default values, Name is empty
    SampleClass.Parameters := ParamRec;
    ....  

  end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Records are usually passed by value into a function/procedure, thus you have to use a var parameter to pass by reference, so change your `ValidateParameters_Record` to

```
procedure ValidateParameters_Record(var aRec: TRec)
```

Then inside `ValidateParameters` you need to create a temporary record, as record-propertys can't be passed as var-parameters, e.g.

```
procedure TSampleClass.ValidateParameters;
var
  Rec: TRec;
begin
  Rec := fParameters.Rec;
  ValidateParameters_Record(Rec);
  fParameters.Rec := Rec;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!